# Apple airport card

Tags: wireless, apple

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu on my Intel-based iMac. However, after the installation, it turns out that Ubuntu is unable to utilize the internal airport extreme card for WiFi. How can I fix this?

The command `lshw -C network` tells me:

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: MCP79 Ethernet
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: a
   bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
   logical name: enp0s10
   version: b1
   serial: 00:25:4b:b1:8f:e2
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.27 latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:27 memory:93586000-93586fff ioport:21e0(size=8) memory:93589000-935890ff memory:93589300-9358930f
*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:18 memory:93200000-93203fff
```

Comment: What does `lshw -C network` tell you?

Comment: It tells what the exact product is (the airport card),  it's bandwidth etc. So it does seem like the computer knows it's there, but the settings won allow me to use it.

Comment: Please Edit your question and insert the output of the `lshw -C network` command.

Comment: Please Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1053957/edit ) your question and insert the output of the lshw -C network command.  You can format it with the `{}` tool. It will fit, and can be made readable.

Comment: @Melebius `BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller` and `driver=b43-pci-bridge`. Type `BCM4322` into the AskUbuntu Search box at the top of the page. Type `b43-pci-bridge` there, too. Read some of the search results, think about trying some of the diagnostic suggestions, think twice about applying any "fixes".